# Using only CSS: How do you center the first line of formatted text and keep the remaining left justified?

Tags: html, css

I can't use javascript.  Just getting that out of the way.

I want to format existing data to format the first line to be bold and centered.  The remaining lines to be justify formatted.  The issue I keep running into is the first like either gets justified or the last wrap for each line gets centered.

Any ideas?

```css
/* Using the following is the closest I've gotten to getting it to work. */
#data {
  white-space: pre-line;
  text-align-last: center;
  text-align: justify;
}


#data::first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h3>This is the data given</h3>
<div id="data">This is the first line!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<br>
<h3>This is what I want</h3>

<div align="center" style="font-weight: bold">This is the first line!</div>
<div align="justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

p.s. bonus points if we can add inline tags via css to wrap data dynamically without Javascript.

Comment: @TemaniAfif The OP says "existing data", so they obviously get this from somewhere as is, and they can't use JavaScript to change it into two separate elements.

Comment: @MrLister i know but maybe we should better think about this `somewhere` in order to get the data like we want instead of trying hard things using CSS [my thoughts]

Comment: RE your bonus points bit: that's the job of XSL Templates, which are like CSS for the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a trick using pseudo element and padding to simulate this behavior. You may adjust the value of padding depending on the text in the first line.

```css
#data {
  white-space: pre-line;
  text-align: justify;
}
#data:before {
  content:" ";
  padding:0 20%;
}

#data::first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h3>This is the data given</h3>
<div id="data">This is the first line!
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best you can get, unfortunately, since there are severe limitations to what you can do with pseudo elements.